# react-router-dom, useHistory() function inside a class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

How i can use the the useHistory function inside my class based component?
I need to redirect my user to a certain page after the login, passing also the state class as an attribute.

[image]

The function onSubmit will execute after the login form submit.

```js
    import React from "react";
    import LoginButton from "../../atoms/AuthenticationButton";
    import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
    import axios from "axios";
    import $ from 'jquery'

    class Login extends React.Component {
        state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            key: '',
            authenticated: false
        };

    onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let navigate = useNavigate();
        $('#errorMessage').html(
            ""
        )
        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dj-rest-auth/login/', {
            username: this.state.username,
            password: this.state.password
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({ key: response.data.key });
            this.setState({ authenticated: true })
            console.log(this.state);
            console.log(response);
            navigate('/dashboard', { replace: true })


        }).catch((error) => {
            if (error.response) {
                for (var field in error.response.data) {
                    for (var errore in field) {
                        if (typeof error.response.data[field][errore] === "string") {
                            $('#errorMessage').append(
                                "<div class='alert alert-secondary' role='alert'>" + error.response.data[field][errore] + "</div>"
                            )
                        }
                    }


                }

            }
        })


    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <form>
                    {/* {'{'}#    username or number field      #{'}'} */}
                    <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: '5%' }}>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                        <div className="col-lg-6">
                            <input type="email"
                                className="form-control input-background-color"
                                id="inputEmail"
                                placeholder="Email or Username"
                                value={this.state.username}
                                onChange={(e) => this.setState({ username: e.target.value })}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                    </div>

                    {/* {'{'}#    password field      #{'}'} */}
                    <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: '3%' }}>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                        <div className="col-lg-6">
                            <input
                                type="password"
                                className="form-control input-background-color"
                                id="inputPassword3"
                                placeholder="Password"
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={(e) => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                    </div>

                    {/* errori da back end o front end */}
                    <div className="col-12 margin-top-5" >
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-2"></div>
                            <div id="errorMessage" className="col-8"></div>
                            <div className="col-2"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {/* {'{'}#  FORGOT PASSWORD   #{'}'} */}
                    <div className="row" style={{ marginTop: '3%' }}>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                        <div className="col-lg-6">
                            <a href="/" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '13px' }}>Forgot Password?</a>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-lg-3" />
                    </div>

                    {/* {'{'}#    LOGIN SUBMIT BUTTON   #{'}'} */}
                    <LoginButton onClick={this.onSubmit} text="Login" marginTop="5%" />
                </form>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Login
```

After the .then in the axios request i want redirect the user that has correctly log on to the /dashboard page.

Comment: You can't use _any_ hooks outside of function-based components.

Comment: try read this: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked with class based components but I know that you should not create an instance of a hook inside a function. So try writing line no.17 either on line no.6 or line no. 14.
If nothing works, so for the workaround you can use

```
window.location.href
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-redirect-to-a-relative-url-in-javascript/